# Why does this object creation loop produce simultaneous constraint errors?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let manImage = UIImage(named: "man.png")

    var buttons = Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: UIButton())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        createButtons()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createButtons() {
        for index in 0...4 {
            buttons[index].setBackgroundImage(manImage, forState: .Normal)
            self.view.addSubview(buttons[index])
            self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: buttons[index],
                attribute: .CenterX,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: view,
                attribute: .CenterX,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

I get `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` errors. Why does this happen, and are there any suggestions to fix this?

Thank you.

I don't know what else to say, but Stack is asking for more text.

Comment: buttons should be allowed to overlap, the constaints that autmatically get added are based on the parent view

Comment: Ok I will make up some code and I will post a different question. I will link it to you in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Actually, I just changed the entire question because I can't post another for 90 minutes.

Comment: ok, yes this makes more sense.  When adding a new UIView object, some constraints automatically get added. You are then adding more constraints on top of it,  set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on your button to false if you want to use your own constaints

Comment: That did it thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buttons` array contains four references to a single instance of `UIButton`. Try this instead:

```
let buttons = (0..<4).map({_ in UIButton()})
```

Also, you probably need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on each button.

Comment: Thank you. I will also make that change to the references.

Comment: Just a tiny followup question. What does (0..<4) do? I'm guessing it's creating a 4 slot array, which is then mapped over with `.map`?

Comment: It creates a [`Range<Int>`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/Range/) of the integers 0 through 3.

Comment: I get it that you shouldn't be referencing to the same instance. Don't know why map doesn't create the same issue.

Comment: The `map` executes the closure four times. Each time the closure is executed, it calls `UIButton.init`. Each call to `UIButton.init` creates a new button.